# How to use C++ std::move on object with asio io_service and acceptor member variables

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move-semantics

I have a software to listen on ports on three NIC, so I defined TCPServer class which uses boost examples, although I am using C++11 and ASIO.

```
class TCPServer {
private:
    asio::io_service& io_service_;
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    TCPListener listener_;       
public:
    TCPServer(asio::io_service& io_service, const tcp::endpoint& listen_endpoint):io_service_(io_service),acceptor_(io_service, listen_endpoint){
        start_accept();
    }
    void quit(){io_service_.stop();}
};
```

I also defined a manager class to manage as a static kind of variable, so inside each server object, the code can tell all of the servers to quit.

```
class TCPManager{
private:
    static asio::io_service io_service[3];
    static TCPServer servers[3];
public:
    void static start(){
        tcp::endpoint listen_endpoint(tcp::v4(), 502);
        TCPServer s0(io_service[0], listen_endpoint);
        servers[0]=s0; // how to move here?
    }
    void quit(){
        servers[0].quit();servers[1].quit();servers[2].quit();
    }
}
```

I would like to move the temporary created variable s0 to be a static variable so it can be accessed elsewhere.  so I am wondering what should be the content of the move assignment constructor?  I do realize that asio::io_service doesn't have a move, so should I just copy it and let it destruct automatically when the temporary variable s0 is out of scope?

### Question:

what do I do here?

```
TCP& operator=TCPServer&& other){
    ... // I intend to move/copy the io_service_, acceptor_, and listener_ variable to this
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: C++11 has no `asio`. It is concept for C++17 based on `boost::asio` library.

Comment: @Zereges Look at this website: http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio and search for Asio and Boost.Asio